# nextjs strapi graphql Dynamic routes error

Tags: next.js, apollo-client, strapi, graphql-js

I’m trying to create a dynamic route and I’m having the following error:

Error: A required parameter (slug) was not provided as a string in getStaticPaths for /roupas/[slug]

this is my query:

```
const GET_CARDS = gql`
query Get_Cards {
  cards{
    data{
      id
      attributes{
        slug
        titulo
        image{
          data{
            attributes{url}
          }
        
        }
        description
        valor
      }
    }
  }
}
`
```

this is my Dynamic page [slug]

```
import GET_CARD_BY_SLUG from "../../lib/queries/getRoupasBySlug"
import {useRouter} from 'next/router'

import { initializeApollo } from "../../lib/apollo"
import GET_CARDS from "../../lib/queries/getRoupas"

const apolloClient = initializeApollo()

export default function Index(){
const router = useRouter()
if(router.isFallback)return null
    return <p>ola</p>

}

export async function getStaticPaths(){
    const {data} = await apolloClient.query({query:GET_CARDS})
    const memorySlugs = data.cards.data;
    const paths = memorySlugs.map(({slug})=>({
       params:{slug}
       
    }))
    return {paths,fallback:true}

}

export async function getStaticProps({params}){
    const {data} = await apolloClient.query({query:GET_CARD_BY_SLUG, variables:{slug:`${params?.slug}`}})
 if(!data.cards.lenght){
    return {notFound:true}
 }
 const card = data.cards[0]

 return{
    props:{
        revalidate:60,
        titulo:card.titulo
       
    }
 }

}
```

when I click on the link to generate the dynamic page, I go to this error screen!
[image: this error]

Comment: Are you sure `slug` is a string? Maybe it's an object with a `slug.current` property or something.

Comment: how would i make the return of this become a string

Comment: Can you include a log of what `slug` contains?

Comment: paths [
  { params: { slug: undefined } },
  { params: { slug: undefined } },
  { params: { slug: undefined } }
]

Comment: Filter out the `undefined` slug values from `memorySlugs` before mapping it. Also, check if you're receiving the right data from your apollo query.